# jmeter load testing tutorial for xmpp

Tags: jmeter

I am new to jmeter, I have downloaded and install xmpp extension for jmeter, however am not able how can I use it. Can someone share tutorial of load testing or test plan for load test of xmpp server.

Thanks in advance.

**EDIT**

[image]

[image]

Comment: I usually summon wizards to do this or use another app.  JMeter is powerful, but a tutorial on using it may require an entire site (as there are books on it).

Answer (score 1):

1. According to the [BlazeMeter Contributes XMPP Testing Capabilities to Open Source JMeter Plugins Project](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/blazemeter-contributes-xmpp-testing-capabilities-open-source-jmeter-plugins-project)

   > BlazeMeter has tested and verified that the new JMeter plugin works with the most common XMPP servers, like Smack, ejabberd, Openfire and HipChat.

   Are you sure you installed the plugin along with dependencies correctly? The recommended way of installing JMeter Plugins and keeping them up-to-date is using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PluginsManager/):

   [image: JMeter Plugins Manager Jabber XMPP support]
2. [XMMP Set Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/XMPPSet/) page contains example [XMPP.jmx](https://jmeter-plugins.org/img/examples/XMPP.jmx) test plan.

---

There is no universal recipe of XMPP/Jabber testing using JMeter as there are different servers which require different configuration. Your best friend is *jmeter.log* file, it normally contains all the information on the cause of script error. If you are sure that details you provided in [XMPP Connection Config](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/XMPPConnection/) and [XMMP Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/XMPPSampler/) are correct but you are not getting the expected result - first thing you should do is looking there. If you will be reporting your problem via [JMeter Plugins forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/jmeter-plugins) - first thing they will ask will be jmeter.log

Comment: exception occurs when i add xmpp.jmx file where is the configuration file for xmpp i have not seen any interface for this?

Comment: Looks like installation issue, make sure you are installing the XMPP Plugin along with all the dependencies using [JMeter Plugins Manager](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-install-jmeter-plugins-manager)

Comment: thanks i have open the xmpp.jmx file and now the interface has been open. is their any tutorial or link which can define the number of steps to successfully load test the xmpp server, using jmeter?

Comment: where is the xmpp sampler.